# timestamp on postgreSQL to unix timestamp

Tags: postgresql, flot, unix-timestamp

I am trying to use FLOT chart to plot values that i have stored in PostgreSQL. One of the axes will have timestamps.
The format that i have stored it the database is: `2013-11-01 00:05:57` (year-month-day hour:minute:second).

I tried the following code to convert this format to UNIX:

```
$postgresql_timestamp= 2013-11-01 00:05:57;
$unix_timestamp= strtotime($postgresql_timestamp);
```

the result that o get is `1383260757` wich corresponds to another date: `2013-10-01 23:05:5`

I think that the problem that I am having is related with the timestamp format on PostgreSQL.

Comment: It's a timezone problem, your dates are different by **ONE** hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I have access to DB with PHP, I used the following code and get good results:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$unix_timstamp = strtotime($postgreSQL_timestamp);
```

Comment: Use extract in your `pg_fetch_all(pg_query($handle, "SELECT extract(...) AS epoch, value FROM table;"));` gives well calculated epoch timestamps as virtual column 'epoch'. Iterate threw big arrays using PHP to parse timestamps can be slow and inefficient.

Answer (score 6):

PostgreSQL supports standard SQL's [`extract()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function, which can convert SQL timestamps to Unix timestamps.

```
select extract(epoch from timestamp '2013-11-01 00:05:57');
```

Comment: Can you supply a link to such a function? I don't recall seeing that in the docs (and a quick look there didn't turn it up).

Comment: @bma: I somehow missed your comment.Sorry about that. But `extract()` is one of [PostgreSQL's Date/Time functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html). It's been supported (and documented) since at least PostgreSQL 7.1.

Comment: If I was referring to `extract()`, I have no idea why I'd ask that. I've been using that function since the mid 2000's. A mystery lost in the depths of time...